# How to clone connections of QObject?

Tags: c++, qt

I have some code like this.

```
class CallFunction : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void call(MyVariant& result);
public:
    CallFunction() {}
    MyVariant eval()
    {
        MyVariant result;
        emit call(result);
        return result;
    }
};

class Block : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void run(MyVariant& result)
    {
        //something actions changing result
    }
};

int main()
{
    CallFunction* callFunction = new CallFunction();
    Block* block = new Block();
    QObject::connect(callFunction,SIGNAL(call(MyVariant&)),block,
        SLOT(run(MyVariant&)));
    callFunction->eval(); //here it's ok. Block::run() is called

    CallFunction* callFunction2 = new CallFunction();
    *callFunction2 = *callFunction;
    callFunction2->eval(); // Here's problem. Block::run doesn't run!
}
```

There are two classes. First one represents object which calls some function. Second one directly runs the function and returns a result.
We need connect the signal CallFunction::call() to the slot Block::run() in order to realize this. Firstly all works ok. But if we clone a CallFunction object, connection disappears. Calling CallFunction::eval() of cloned object has no effects. I suppose I need to overload assignment operator of class CallFunction, but I can't find any information about cloning of existing connections.

Comment: How do you clone your objects? `QObject` has disabled copy ctor and disabled assignment operator.

Comment: Why you want to do this ? Do not clone a QObject type,  [Object Model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/object.html).

Comment: Btw, you may use an object factory pattern to create objects with necessary connections.

Comment: I have already abandoned signals-slots mechanism for this case and I'm using now method pointers. It works fine.

Comment: "I have already abandoned signals-slots mechanism for this case" You don't have to. But you have to tell us *what* are you trying to achieve. So far you've only told us *how* you wanted to do it, and that it didn't work. It'd be better to edit your question with a detailed description of your ultimate goal. Most likely, there's a better, simpler solution to your problem.